# How to get the SPWebService from SPServices?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have done a sample but not getting the SPWebService.Please see the below code

```
        SPFarm spFarmObject = SPFarm.Local; 

        lblServices.Text = "Number of Services in This farm : " + Convert.ToString(spFarmObject.Services.Count);
        foreach(SPService spServiceObject in spFarmObject.Services)
        {
            string webServiceName=spServiceObject.Name;
            if (webServiceName== "SPWebService ")
            {
                lblWebService.Text = spServiceObject.Name;
                ///I have to do some code here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to get `SPWebService`

```
SPServiceCollection services = SPFarm.Local.Services;

foreach (SPService curService in services)
{
  if (curService is SPWebService)
  {
    SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)curService;

    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
    {
      // here you can do something with webApp
    }
  }
}
```

[Source - Iterating through all Web Applications in a SharePoint farm](http://weblogs.asp.net/jevgeni/archive/2009/12/27/iterating-through-all-web-applications-in-a-sharepoint-farm.aspx)

Comment: Ok it is working fine

Comment: You can mark it as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Why you type casted SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)curService;if curService is SPWebService then why?

Comment: If you look at foreach loop, curService object is of type SPService and hence you need to cast it to  SPWebService

Comment: ok ok.I forgot that